# How to split transactions with iDeal?

Tags: payment

I have seen the following can be done with Paypal. But is it posseble to make it happen using iDeal?

This is what I want:

1. Customer buys product for $20 in the webshop
2. $8 of the $20 must be deposited at the bankaccount of administrator 1
3. $12 of the $20 must be deposited at the bankaccount of administrator 2

Of course I can say to one of the administrators to transfer the rest of money to the other. But since we are talking about thousands of customers and transactions this is not the most practical solution.

Can it be done with iDeal? Of are there any alternatives?